# Efficient method to do AES 256bit encryption in python

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I need to encrypt a large file using python. Doing some online research suggested me several modules. I am a bit confused to chose what to use.

I want to make sure that it must work efficiently as much as possible with python.

What is the most efficient python AES 256 encryption module?

Comment: SHA 256 is not even encryption.

Comment: Updated the question. @user2357112

Comment: AES is a block cipher, it's not really suitable for encrypting files (which are much larger than a single block).  You want something like python-gnupg, which has facilities for encrypting a file in a way that uses AES, but doesn't have the vulnerabilities and security holes that you typically see in code that you write yourself.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Completely incorrect! AES is the correct algorithm to use. Almost all implementations support multiple block input and internally apply the block algorithm to the input.

Comment: @zaph: That's all I'm trying to say, really.  Using AES directly is just a recipe for disaster unless crypto is your specialty, and for most application programmers, it's not.  TLS can encrypt files just fine... it encrypts them in transit, not while they are stored on disk.

Comment: @zaph: An "AES" implementation only handles one size--128 bits.  An AES-CBC implementation handles a multiple of 128 bits.  Etc.

Comment: @zaph: On a personal note, the "you do not realize" comments are uncalled for.  Please keep the discussion about programming and cryptography, we are not here to discuss me.

Comment: @DietrichEppq Encryption in trasnsit is not file encryption, TLS is not used to encrypt files. CBC is just one mode of many and does not make AES or any other block encryption handle more than one block,  it is the usual implementation of AES that allows it to encrypt more than one block.

Comment: @DietrichEpp The problem here is mis-information about AES usual implementations and the role of TLS.

Comment: @zaph: When I upload a file to Facebook, the file is encrypted with TLS.  Yes, usually AES implementations also implement various block modes in addition to the AES cipher itself.  However, choosing the right block mode, choosing the key, figuring out padding, integrity checks, etc. are all beyond the scope of AES and are quite essential if you want any reasonable guarantee of security, which is why an AES implementation is simply insufficient for encryption.  I hope this clarifies my earlier statements.

Comment: @DietrichEpp TLS is not used to encrypt files, stating that is it a file encryption option is disingenuous and incorrect. Files transferred under TLS end up at the receiver **unencrypted** so it really is not file encryption. TLS has no concept of content, it is just a stream of bytes, to call that file encryption is pushing things past any reasonable limits. implementations can be entirely different.

Comment: @DietrichEpp It does not matter what implementation is used to encrypt a file, if AES is the encryption algorithm we say it is encrypted with AES. The encryption and decryption implementations can be entirely different as is common in cross platform situations. In many cases the developer writing the code on one side has no idea of the implementation on the other side. All that needs to be known are the encryption options and encrypted data layout. I agree that using a higher level implementation is the best course if possible but some times that is not possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135395/discussion-between-dietrich-epp-and-zaph).

Answer (score 1):

You can try '[PyCryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)' package that supports AES-NI mode if your hardware supports it.
PyCryptodome supports AES encrypion with 256 bits key.
You can use GCM mode if you seek for encryption+authentication. If authentication is not in your interest you can use CTR mode.

Code example for CTR mode:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
# encryption
    cipher = AES.new(key_bytes, AES.MODE_CTR, use_aesni='True')
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(data_as_bytes)
    nonce = cipher.nonce
# decryption
    cipher = AES.new(key_bytes, AES.MODE_CTR, nonce=nonce, use_aesni='True')
    plaintext_as_bytes = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

Code example for GCM mode:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
# encryption
    cipher = AES.new(key_bytes, AES.MODE_GCM, use_aesni='True')
    nonce = cipher.nonce
    ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data_as_bytes)
# decryption
    cipher = AES.new(key_bytes, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=nonce, use_aesni='True')
    plaintext_as_bytes = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
    try:
         cipher.verify(tag)
         print("The message is authenticated")
    except ValueError:
         print("Key incorrect or message corrupted")
```

To check if your hardware supports AES-NI mode you can check the answers [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4590/tool-or-process-to-check-for-aes-ni-support-on-processor).